# twitter bootstrap carousel - slide images on mouseover untill mouseout

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I am using the twitter bootstrap carousel to show images sliding over my page.
It works perfectly fine.

Instead of sliding the images on mouse click, I wanted the images to slide when i hover mouse on arrows. I did make a change and it works (as shown below).

boostrap-carousel.js, line 193 
$(document).on('mouseover.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide], [data-slide-to]', function (e)

But the problem is - I want the images to be sliding until the mouse is over the arrow and stop sliding when i move my mouse away.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of changing the `bootstrap-carousel.js` you can use Javascript/jQuery to control the carousel. A delay/timer can be used to repeat the mouseover function which triggers the normal left/right functions of the carousel controls.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval:false}); /* init the carousel but don't start it */
var myInterval=false;
$('.carousel-control').mouseover(function() {
    var ctrl = $(this);
    var interval=300;

    myInterval = setInterval(function(){
         ctrl.trigger("click");
    },interval);
});

$('.carousel-control').mouseout(function(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = false;
});
```

Working demo on Bootply: **http://bootply.com/Gyfhc2kCwd**

Comment: Thanks Skelly. That was a perfect solution.

Comment: Is that possible only on hover of image carousel will start and stop on mouse leave Instead of carousel-control.